# How to hide databases in Azure SQL?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I know the question was asked, but non of the suggestions helped.
I have databases from multiple users on my Azure SQL server.

There is a login '**USER1**', and a user created from that login, which is owner of '**DATABASE1**'.

There is a login '**USER2**', and a user created from that login, which is owner of '**DATABASE2**'

When USER1 connects to the Server, it enumerates/sees the Database DATABASE2. It can't open it, but sees it.

The following commands executed by the sysadmin on the master, or the user databases, don't work:

```
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [PUBLIC]
```

or

```
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [USER1]
```

The error is:

```
'Securable class 'server' not supported in the server scope in this version of SQL Server.'
```

Comment: Why not *not* (intentional double negative) create them a `LOGIN`? Azure SQL Databases are contained database, so if they should only have access to the database, why create them a `LOGIN`?

Comment: @Larnu, you are right. This is what I discovered as a workaround. However, the problem is that the application using the database does not support the connection string to contain Database name. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps to restrict users in **Azure SQL DB**.

> When USER1 connects to the Server, it enumerates/sees the Database DATABASE2. It can't open it, but sees it.

**USER1** has been granted the **VIEW ANY DATABASE** permission. If **USER1** has been granted the **VIEW ANY DATABASE** permission on the **Azure SQL server**, they will be able to see all databases on the server, even if they don't have permission to access them.

Check the **VIEW ANY DATABASE** on **Azure SQL Database** using below script.

```
SELECT  *  FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') WHERE permission_name =  'VIEW ANY DATABASE';
```

[image]

> This is possible for a single user login as you can only assign
> ownership of a database to a single user and deny **VIEW ANY
> DATABASE** as below, see the [Ms
> Doc](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a989ca87-660d-41c4-9dac-70b29a83ddfb/hide-database-names-from-unauthroized-users-in-ssms?forum=sqlsecurity)
> created by `Hale`
>
> 1. Right click the users logon under the users database if they exist and remove.
>
> > (Note: Do not remove the user from under the main security login)
>
> 2.Run the below query.
>
> ```
> USE <customersdatabase> 
>     ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::<customerdatabase> to <customerlogin>
>     
>     USE MASTER
>     
>     DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO <customerlogin>
> ```

You can also disable public access on **Azure SQL DB** from portal as below.

**Go to your Azure SQL Server > Networking > Public Access**.

[image]

I can be able to see only one database not other database once i logged in to the user.

[image]

Reference:
[How to hide Microsoft SQL databases that a user does not have access to](https://community.pyramidanalytics.com/t/63byya/how-to-hide-sql-databases-that-a-user-does-not-have-access-to#:%7E:text=1%29%20Login%20to%20SQL%20Management,connect%20to%20your%20SQL%20instance.&text=2%29%20Expand%20Servers%20and%20select,view%20permission%20on%20specific%20databases.) created by -   `Daniel`

Comment: In AzureSQL it doesn't really work that way. I ran successfully the ALTER AUTHORIZATION on the desired Database. However, "DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO <customerlogin>" returns an error:
"Securable class 'server' not supported in the server scope in this version of SQL Server.
"

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way so far, with Azure SQL, seems to be the usage of the so called Contained User.
A user has to be created at the Database level, without being linked to a login. Any Login in SQL is at the SQL server level and will be able to see the databases attached on that server. (Limitation in the Azure SQL)

Creating the user by running the following commands on the Desired Database:

```
CREATE USER <USERNAME> WITH PASSWORD= 'ExtremelySecretPAss123!';

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER <USERNAME>; 
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER <USERNAME>;
```

Now to connect to the database (not the SQL server), the following should happen:
Enter the SQL server, username and password in SQL Management Studio
[image: SQL login]

Press the "Options" button and under the Connection Properties, enter the name of the database the user needs to login to.

[image]